# To have a Bat file see if the document is open, before opening the document again, but still executing the bat file

Tags: vba, batch-file, ms-word

I have a word document with around a hundred bookmarks, each with a Macro programmed in for each Bookmark.

I created a word macro for each bookmark:

```
Sub Coronado()
    Application.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Coronado").Select
End Sub
```

And then created a bat file to take me to the bookmark I need to go to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe" ""C:\Users\1241\Desktop\WorkFiles\HotelDel.docm"" /mCoronado
```

My new question is:
Is there a way to run this bat file, so that if the document is already open, it will just run the macro without reopening the document again.
I have several of these macros and bat files I am using, and would like the bat files to go to the macros in the word document without reopening the word document each time. After a while I would have numerous instances of the word document open, and then have to close them all.

OK, I have decided to go with VB Scripts, It has been a much easier process.

What I am doing is using a programmed voice software to activate scripts.
While I am talking to the customer, I say the name of the Word document, and then my voice command brings up the word document. As the customer asks questions, then I say the name of the question, and the voice command I have programmed in uses a VB Script to automatically go to that bookmark where the information I am trying to find for the customer is. This way I cut down on a lot of time searching through this word document fort the information the customer is looking for. This is all done with voice activated commands, such as "Parking Policy" or "Pet Policy". When I say these words, the computer automatically takes me to that bookmark in the document with no typing involved.

The issue I am having now, Is how to program a global Variable for each document I bring up. I need all previous variables cleared, and then I need the new variable put in place. For instance I say the name "Hotel Del Coronado" and that information document is brought forward on the screen. I need the path of that document to become the new variable for Hotel. Now when I say the name of the bookmark, it uses the path of the current document to go to that bookmark in the current document. This way I only have to program the Bookmark Scripts once. Each of my documents have the same bookmarks. So if I have the Variable Hotel set for the new document, Then all of the bookmark commands will be set for the new document.

Comment: If the file is already open why do you need to run the .bat? Why can't you just run the macro?

Comment: What process is running the bat file and for what purpose?